# Smartface.io: strange dataset behavior when multiple dataset reference same table

Tags: smartface.io

I have two datasets: DS1 and DS2.
DS1 is linked to table T1 only,
DS2 is linked to T1 and T2 tables (via SELECT using both tables and filtering T1).
When starting my app everything is looking right.
If I add several records to T1 from within my app using:

```
DS1.add();
...
DS1.commit();
DS1.refresh();
```

then DS2 gets crazy - values move from one field to another within records.
Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems the problem has something to do with a datetime field in T1. DS1 and DS2 have string fields linked to the datetime fied in T1. Inserting datetime object via dataset makes values shift between fields

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported issue, will be fixed with the upcoming release.